# Remove whitespace from a set of documents linux

Tags: linux, bash

I want to remove all the white spaces from a given text files (about 200,000 of them).

I know how to remove whitespace for one of them:

```
cat file.txt | tr -d " \t\n\r"
```

How I can do that for all folder?

Answer (score 3):

One way is by iterating on the files in the current directory:

```
for file in *; do
   cat $file | tr -d " \t\n\r" 
done
```

Or, maybe better:

```
for file in *; do
   sed -i 's/ //g' $file
done
```

Comment: you need to redirect the output after the `tr`/`sed` commands or add `-i.bak` for `sed`

Comment: @Maroun: Globbing (`*`) becomes problematic with thousands of files.

Comment: @Cyrus Can you please explain why? Or, what else do you recommend (I'll edit my answer).

Comment: @Maroun: The length of the command line is limited to the value (in bytes) displayed with `getconf ARG_MAX`.

Comment: What's the point of having `sed` create a backup file if you immediately remove it? Also please fix the errors reported by http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: The poster has stated that the pattern `" \t\n\r"` is correct.

Comment: @tripleee I'm on MacOS, `sed` works a bit different here. OP can get rid of the `-i` if he's using Ubuntu.

Comment: You can use `-i ""` on MacOS and related platforms (*BSD etc).

Comment: @Cyrus The `ARG_MAX` limit applies to the `exec` system call. The shell can, and typically does, handle wildcard expansion in a way where this limit does not apply. (Running an external command on the result of the expansion will still fail, of course; but that is not the scenario here.)

Comment: With second option new lines are still not deleted. :/

Answer (score 2):

I would use `find` for this:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i ':a;N;s/[[:space:]]*//g;ba' {}  \;
```

This assumes the files are of reasonable sizes `:-/`

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `for` loop

i.e.

```
for i in *
do
   cat $i | tr -d " \t\n\r" > $i.tmp
   rm -f $i
   mv $i.tmp $i
done;
```

Comment: Better avoiding `cat` for this. See [here](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html).

Comment: @Maroun - I agree. Was going to update my answer - but you beat me to it

Comment: The link to the *Jargon file* has pretty bad formatting errors. Perhaps instead link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat